# Qual é a finalidade do comando unsafe?

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem, memória

Vi o uso do comando `unsafe`, neste [código](https://gist.github.com/goldshtn/7021608) na declaração deste método:

```
public unsafe static int GetSquareStack(int value) {...}
```

Dentro do método parece haver manipulação de ponteiros `*`, não sabia que C# dava suporte a ponteiros.

---

## Dúvidas

Eu gostaria de saber qual é a finalidade do comando `unsafe` e em quais situações é aconselhável seu uso?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não é bem um comando mas sim uma marcação. Ela serve para instruir o compilador a aceitar operações ditas inseguras por parte do programador.

Essas operações são principalmente:

- manipulação de ponteiros:

  - operador `*` para obter o valor apontado
  - operadores matemáticos: `+`, `-`, `++`, `--` são os mais comuns
- obtenção de endereço de memória usando operador `&`
- travamento de objetos na memória para utilização em APIs não gerenciadas

  - essas APIs geralmente são PInvokes, veja atributo [DllImport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Esses recursos são ditos `unsafe` (inseguros) pois o compilador não tem como garantir que o programador estará sempre acessando endereços de memória válidos... afinal é possível colocar um valor qualquer num ponteiro e tentar acessar, o que pode trazer dados que estão por exemplo fora do array, ou fora da área de memória do objeto.

### Quando usar?

Esse recurso é utilizado em duas situações pelo que eu bem me lembro:

- operações com API não managed

  Quando se chama uma API externa não managed e se deseja passar um ponteiro para ela preencher com algo, se a memória tiver sido alocada de forma gerenciada, você deverá travar as posições de memória de forma que o Garbage Collector não mude a memória do objeto de posição até que a trava seja liberada.
- operações com arrays que exigem extrema performance

  Um exemplo prático é a manipulação de imagens pixel a pixel. É muito mais rápido iterar os pixels sem fazer nenhuma forma de checagem de limites do array.

  Outros exemplos, todos incluem a manipulação de dados em larga escala:

  - compressão de dados
  - criptografia de dados
  - cálculo de Hash de dados, inclusive assinaturas
  - trabalhos com dados de áudio
  - etc.

### Como usar?

Primeiramente é necessário que o projeto seja marcado como contendo código `unsafe`. Isso é necessário pois o assembly gerado terá restrições maiores quanto a sua utilização, de forma que em certos contextos um erro na utilização pode comprometer o processo que está utilizando o assembly. Por exemplo, imagine carregar um assembly `unsafe` no SQL Server, ele não pode deixar um usuário qualquer fazer isso sem autorização suficiente.

A palavra chave `unsafe` deve ser usada para marcar o método que será implementado usando recursos de ponteiros e fixação de memória.

E finalmente você pode usar a palavra chave `fixed` em um ponteiro, para marcar a instância daquele objeto como sendo fixa. A instrução `fixed` se estende por um bloco de execução, sendo que ao final deste a instância do objeto é liberada para ser movida pelo Garbage Collector.

### O que significa no código que você indicou

No código que você indicou a utilização do recurso é para comparar a performance entre duas maneiras de alocar memória para um array. Entretanto, existem ainda outras formas de alocar memória além dessas. Vou listá-las:

- Alocação gerenciada na Heap Gerenciada:

  O método `GetSquare` aloca memória managed na Heap Gerenciada, que é como se fosse uma coleção arbitrária de objetos, que podem ser criados e destruídos. Quando um objeto é criado, o alocador tem que procurar uma área de memória livre que seja do tamanho do objeto a ser alocado, e quando o objeto é destruído pelo Garbage Collector, a área utilizada é liberada, sendo que de tempos em tempos a área é comprimida, ou seja, os objetos que estiverem em áreas adjacentes são reorganizados para ocupar os possíveis buracos que ficaram na memória... é como se fosse uma desfragmentação da memória.

  Por isso tudo essa forma de alocar memória é um pouco lenta se comparada à próxima forma que o código testa: com uso de `stackalloc`.
- Alocação na Pilha

  O método `GetSquareStack` aloca memória com `stackalloc`, que não utiliza a Heap mas sim a Pilha, que é uma área de memória em que os itens alocados são colocados um após o outro, não há necessidade de buscar uma área livre. Além disso, um objeto só pode ser deletado dessa área de memória se ele for o último que lá reside. Esse processo de alocar e desalocar áreas de memória na pilha é feita automaticamente quando um método é chamado ou quando o método retorna de forma segura. Toda a memória da pilha alocada por um método será automaticamente liberada quando o método terminar. Assim sendo o C# não permite alocar manualmente memória nesse espaço pois do contrário seria possível retornar um objeto que reside nessa memória, e portanto seria invalidado ao término desse mesmo método.

  Por isso `stackalloc` não é seguro. Está se alocando memória e obtendo-se um ponteiro, que ao final do método será invalidado. Mas ainda assim, como o programador pôs as mãos nesse ponteiro, agora ele pode retornar esse ponteiro, que será inválido fora do método.
- Alocação usando `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`

  Essa forma de alocação de memória irá alocar na Heap Global não gerenciada. O Garbage Collector não possui influência sobre esta área de memória, portando tudo que for alocado ali já está fixo por natureza.

  Essa forma de alocar memória é igual ao da Heap Gerenciada em termos de performance. Só o gerenciamento pelo GC que não terá impacto.

Answer (score 7):

Ele define que um bloco de código (pode ser um método todo, como na sintaxe da pergunta) poderá usar recursos da linguagem considerados inseguros.

Esta é uma forma de garantir que o recurso não seja usado inadvertidamente e também permitir que outras partes do código por padrão possam ter uma otimização mais agressiva dada a segurança garantida.

Nele é permitido o uso de ponteiros para memória. Ponteiros são inseguros por natureza. É possível usar até aritmética. Existem algumas limitações, a memória continua gerenciada pelo *garbage collector*, mas o acesso à memória pode ser feito direto ao local pretendido sem maiores garantias. Isto pode ser útil para dar mais performance.

Se olhar alguns códigos do .NET verá seu uso. A classe `String` usa bastante para obter o máximo de performance.

Também há algum uso de interoperabilidade onde o ponteiro bruto é mais adequado, me geral por questões de performance, mas por especificação também, caso típico do COM e outras APIs do Windows.

Quando precisa de acesso direto à disco (ou pelo menos arquivos mapeados em memória) ele é útil.

A manipulação de mapas de bits também é um uso importante.

Também pode usar `fixed` para indicar para o GC que um objeto não pode ser movido (o que pode trazer problemas de fragmentação de memória, nada crítico, porém).

Praticamente nunca deve usar. Nunca precisei. Mas adoro saber que o recurso está disponível para o dia que precisar (até acho que tenho uma situação que usarei).

Em geral o pessoal adora fazer otimização prematura, mas por sorte este não é um recurso frequentemente abusado.

Seu uso só é permitido com diretiva de compilação. Mais uma medida para não usar inadvertidamente.

Normalmente um código assim exige mais privilégios no sistema de segurança do .NET. A segurança do código não pode ser verificada.

[Documentação da Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).