# Como usar código unsafe em um Web Site

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, compilação

Estava procurando praticar o uso de ponteiros em C#, para isso criei em um website o seguinte método:

```
public static Nodo[] MontaTree(){ //... código ... }
```

Obviamente o código acima não possibilita usar ponteiros, pra isso precisamos da *keyword* `unsafe`. Coloquei ela no método, deixando a assinatura assim:

```
public static unsafe Nodo[] MontaTree(){ //... código ... }
```

Mas recebi a seguinte mensagem ao compilar:

> Unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe

Ao pesquisar no Google, a solução parecia simples: Apenas ligar a opção `Allow unsafe code` na tab Build dentro das propriedades do projeto, porém não consigo encontrar em nenhum lugar essa opção no meu projeto, como mostra a imagem:

[image: Build Website]

Alguém sabe se estou fazendo algo errado? Aonde fica essa opção no VS2015? Ou não é possível em WebSites?

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual é a finalidade do comando unsafe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142030/qual-%C3%A9-a-finalidade-do-comando-unsafe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do @jbueno, quando o projeto não é uma aplicação web essa opção não aparece na tab build em propriedades, tenta colocar o seguinte trecho no seu **web.config**:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.codedom>
      <compilers>
          <compiler 
              language="c#;cs;csharp" 
              extension=".cs" 
              compilerOptions="/unsafe"
              type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

fonte:[how to add unsafe keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867613/how-to-add-unsafe-keyword-in-web-based-asp-net-application-c-sharp)

Comment: Olá, funcionou perfeitamente, mas a mensagem de "Unsafe code may only appear..." continua aparecendo, apesar de o código compilar normalmente. Sabe se isso pode acarretar algum problema?

Comment: Sincronizados...

Comment: @ismael Como assim?

Comment: @ArturoTemplário Foi um comentário pro Mathias sobre "quase" postar ao mesmo tempo a reposta. Demorei pq fui formatar acrescentando a tag <configuration>.

Comment: complementei, ty @ismael.

Answer (score 4):

#### Se a aplicação for um ASP.NET site

Adicione a tag `compilers` no arquivo web.config (dentro de `configuration -> system.codedom`)

```xml
<configuration>
 <!-- outras tags -->

  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" compilerOptions="/unsafe" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

---

#### Se for uma aplicação ASP.NET normal

Clique com o botão direito no projeto (no arquivo **csproj**), depois no último item (*properties*).

Você vai ver uma janela como esta abaixo.

Então é só clicar em **build** e depois marcar a caixa de seleção "*Allow unsafe code*".

[image: properties page]

Comment: Olá, eu também vi respostas semelhantes a essa em outros lugares (SO em inglês/MSDN), mas não tem essa opção em WebSite, apenas Web Application :/, vi um pessoal falando em colocar algumas configurações no JSON de configuração, mas não tenho esse arquivo também

Comment: pronto @ArturoTemplário

Comment: muito obrigado! Ele agora compila, mas a mensagem de erro ainda continua, apesar de não aparentar nenhum problema. Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: É uma mensagem de erro mesmo é apenas um _warning_ (aviso)?

Comment: Geralmente warnings são os sublinhados verdes, não? Este está em vermelho, o que é realmente intrigante, pois estou acostumado a sublinhados vermelhos não deixarem compilar

Answer (score 3):

Você tem que fazer na mão mexendo no arquivo `Web.config`:

```
<compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx"
warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701 /unsafe+"/>
```

De qualquer forma se é para testar o recurso o mais adequado é criar a aplicação mais simples possível, no caso seria uma aplicação console.

Answer (score 1):

Adicione em seu Web.Config o seguinte tag:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler
       language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
       compilerOptions="/unsafe"
       type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```