# Quais as consequências de programar em 32 bits ou 64 bits?

Tags: c#, .net, memória, 64-bits, 32-bits

Seria só a capacidade de memória que é limitada a 4 GB  em 32 bits?

Preciso ter preocupações específicas?

Eu sei o que tem de diferente em C, quero saber sobre C#.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Deve saber que o ponteiro de 32 bits tem 4 bytes e em arquitetura 64 bits tem 8 bytes. Isso tem profundas mudanças internas no .NET.

O consumo de memória de todos objetos que tenham ponteiros será maior. Apesar do C# não possuir ponteiros livres (a não ser em contexto [`unsafe`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142030/101)) há ponteiros opacos em tudo que é um tipo por referência, já que o ponteiro é o mecanismo de se obter a referência.

O consumo do próprio objeto aumenta mesmo que ele não tenha membros por referência. Todo objeto no *heap* precisa de duas [palavras de CPU](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185523/101), uma delas é um ponteiro para o tipo daquele objeto que é importante para reflexão, gerenciamento de memória pelo *garbage collector* e polimorfismo. A outra palavra tem múltiplas funções e pode ser um ponteiro também, e deve ter o mesmo tamanho que a palavra anterior  até porque questões de [alinhamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50614/101).

Então fica óbvio que havendo o ponteiro, esse cabeçalho que todo objeto possui será maior.

Além disto o tipo [`IntPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) tem seu tamanho alterado já que ele é ponteiro.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 8):

Além da memória, existem outras sim:

- DLLs são carregadas em aplicações com bits equivalentes. Se tentar carregar uma DLL 32-bit em uma aplicação 64-bit, será lançada a exceção `BadImageFormatException`
- Tipos específicos da plataforma, `IntPtr` por exemplo, têm diferentes tamanhos.
- A comunicação interprocessos pode ter problemas quando feita entre processos 32-bit e 64-bit. Por exemplo, o `ReadProcessMemory` pode falhar quando um processo 32-bit tenta ler de um processo 64-bit.
- Existe também a situação do [Registry Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384235(VS.85).aspx), explicado no MSDN.

Você vai encontrar problemas dependendo da complexidade da aplicação.

Answer (score 6):

Uma informação a mais, para complementar as respostas do Rodrigo e do Maniero.

Se você compilar a aplicação como 64 bits, ela não vai rodar em máquinas com processadores 32 bits (ou menos).

Como faz muito tempo que não vemos esse tipo de máquina (o Windows XP já tinha versões 64 bits em meados do período Jurássico), isso só seria problema se você tentasse executar um aplicativo em uma peça de museu. Mas acho que vale a pena mencionar, de qualquer forma.

Agora, sério mesmo, a única aplicação prática que vejo para a compilação em 32 bits é para atualizar DLL's de aplicações 32 bits - e essas ainda existem e são muito comuns. Se você for atualizar uma DLL de uma aplicação dessas, você tem que manter o padrão de bits, caso contrário haverá incompatibilidade.