# Quando usar ponteiros e quando usar referências?

Tags: c#, .net, ponteiro, estilo-de-codificação

Entendo a diferença entre uma referência e um ponteiro, como explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56470/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-ponteiro-e-refer%c3%aancia), no entanto, não sei os critérios para usar um ou o outro.

Tenho este trecho de código:

```
record struct Person
{
    public int Age;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person personA = new Person() { Age = 10 };

    ModifyPersonRef(ref personA);
    Console.WriteLine(personA);

    ModifyPersonPointer(&personA);
    Console.WriteLine(personA);
}

static void ModifyPersonRef(ref Person person)
{
    person.Age = 15;
}

static void ModifyPersonPointer(Person* pointerToPerson)
{
    (*pointerToPerson).Age = 30;
}
```

`ModifyPersonRef` e `ModifyPersonPointer` fazem a mesma coisa, mas um com referência e outro com ponteiros.

Quando devo usar referência e quando devo usar ponteiros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em essência deve usar referências e não pensar em ponteiros. Seja referências através de classes, já que todas implicitamente usam referências, seja em tipos por valor que são explicitados como referências com [`ref`, `out` e `in`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82630/101).

Em alguns casos é melhor usar um [`Span`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou algum tipo que ajuda ter uma referência, ou até mesmo colocar um tipo por valor dentro de outro por referência pode ser melhor que usar ponteiro (em raros casos). Em versões mais novas do C# o ponteiro deve ser muito evitado, até porque só dá para usá-lo em contexto [`unsafe`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/142034/101), que o nome já indica que precisa tomar extremo cuidado.

O ponteiro só é útil em casos que precisa interagir com o sistema operacional, o hardware ou algum serviço que exija uso do ponteiro diretamente, ou seja, interoperabilidade, e é bem raro precisar fazer isso. Além disso por uma questão de eficiência pode-se optar por ele para ter mais controle sobre a memória ou implementar um algoritmo que acesse a memória da forma mais bruta possível e nenhum recurso normal do C# ou otimização do compilador/JITter conseguiu entregar o que o ponteiro poderia entregar. Novamente, é raro ter essa necessidade em versões mais novas da linguagem e biblioteca. Boa parte da existência dele é justamente permitir que a biblioteca use e entregue coisas mais seguras para o programador final sem tratamento especial da linguagem ou alguma gambiarra.

Antes, um exemplo que se usava muito era manipular uma *string*, e eventualmente outra coleção, de forma mais rápida porque não tinha um recurso bom para isso quando o máximo do desempenho era exigido.

O exemplo mostrado na pergunta é absolutamente sem necessidade, não haverá qualquer ganho, e haverá perda de segurança (se mudar para `unsafe` para ele poder ser compilado).

Um problema do objeto que será acessado com ponteiro é que ele precisa ser fixo, porque se o GC mudá-lo de lugar o ponteiro não funciona mais, sem aviso e de forma insegura.

Até mesmo em baixo nível existem métodos para acessar a memória de forma segura, principalmente em [`Marshal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e também [`Unsafe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que apesar do nome é bem mais seguro que o ponteiro direto em vários casos, mas também precisa de bastante cuidado.

Se pode fazer com `ref` ou algo parecido, faça. Preocupe-se com ponteiro só quando estiver fazendo algo mais baixo nível ou não está atingindo metas de performance e não tenha mais nada que possa melhorar no código normal para conseguir isso, aí fará um experimento se o ponteiro dará melhor resultado, nem sempre acontece.

Quase todos os exemplos que encontrar com ponteiro são ingênuos, necessários apenas em versões antigas ou errados. Até mesmo na documentação só demonstra o mecanismo, não o uso adequado.

Comment: Então quase nunca será necessário usar ponteiros :-)